# Is there a way to limit the score to 7 points when scored

Tags: python, pygame

```
if fireBall.rect.x>=690:
      score_1+=1
      fireBall.ballspeed[0] = -fireBall.ballspeed[0]
      fireBall.rect.center = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center
  if fireBall.rect.x<=0:
      score_2+=1
      fireBall.ballspeed[0] = -fireBall.ballspeed[0]
      fireBall.rect.center = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center
  if fireBall.rect.y>490:
      fireBall.ballspeed[1] = -fireBall.ballspeed[1]
  if fireBall.rect.y<0:
      fireBall.ballspeed[1] = -fireBall.ballspeed[1]
```

I am making a ping pong game, I wanted the score to go to 7, but in my code the players can score continuously would keep on increasing.

Comment: What should happen when the score reaches 7? Anyway, I don't understand the question, what's wrong with `if score_1 == 7: ... (do somthing)`? Or do you search for `score_1 = min(score_1+1, 7)`

Comment: score_1 = score_1 + 1 if score_1 < 7 else 7

Comment: score_1 = min(score_1+1, 7) helps

Comment: `score_1 = min(score_1+1, 7)` and `score_1 = score_1+1 if score_1<7 else 7` are both possible solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit a value you can either use the built-in [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function

```py
score_1 = min(score_1+1, 7)
```

or a [Conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```py
score_1 = score_1+1 if score_1 < 7 else 7
```